# Embedded Youtube player not responding in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, youtube, embed

I'm using CSS to stylize a website and have an embedded youtube clip inside of several DIVs like so:

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="outer">
        <img src="images/sidebar.png"/ class="sidepic">
        <div id="look">

            <iframe width="500px" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" height="280px" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/J-U9aYeLvX0?wmode=opaque&feature=player_profilepage&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen seamless></iframe>

            <img src="images/content-01.png" class="bigpic" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine in Internet Explorer, but doesn't work in Chrome. The video doesn't detect any hover or clicking, as though it's a static image or hidden.

I've tried to use the ?wmode=opaque / transparent tags recommended in other threads on this site, but it doesn't seem to work. Removing the iframe from the DIV tags allows the video to play, but distorts the rest of the page.

Comment: Fixed by adding z-index:50; to the class code. Courtesy of a phone call to a friend.